# Tooling API Queries in Dev Console only show one row

Tags: soql, developer-console, tooling-api

When submitting a SOQL query in the Dev Console using the Tooling API only one result row shows, even though more overall rows are returned, as confirmed by the "Query Results" notice above the returned row.

For example, the query below to find indexed fields on the Account only displays one returned row, but has a "Query Results - Total Rows" of 51.

```
select id, DataType, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' AND IsIndexed = TRUE
```

The same query delivered through the REST API returns the full expected number of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be because the `Id` returned is the same for all `FieldDefinition` records (no clue why...)

With this modified query:

```
select DurableId, DataType, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' AND IsIndexed = TRUE
```

you will get all the indexed fields

Answer (score 0):

As per support, the Tooling API will only return the first row of a SOQL query by design to avoid potential performance issues. REST API is the recommended way to get multiple rows returned.